# RSpec test failed show flash message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

My Controller (User Controller)

```
 def reset_password
      @user = User.find_by_reset_code(params[:reset_code]) unless params[:reset_code].nil?     

      if request.post?    
        if @user && @user.update_attributes(:password => params[:user][:password], :password_confirmation => params[:user][:password_confirmation])
          self.current_user = @user
          @user.delete_reset_code
          flash[:success] = t('helpers.password_reset_successful')
          render :template => "sessions/new"
        else
          flash[:error] = t('helpers.password_reset_error')
          redirect_to root_path
        end
      end
   end
```

I would like test it and I do...

```
 it "should have a flash message" do
    @attr = { :password => "newpassword", :password_confirmation => "newpassword" }
    @user.reset_code = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest( Time.now.to_s.split(//).sort_by {rand}.join )

    post :reset_password, :reset_code => @user.reset_code, :password => @attr[:password], :password_confirmation => @attr[:password_confirmation]
    flash[:success].should == I18n.t('helpers.password_reset_successful')
  end
```

But I've exception in Rspec -

```
Failure/Error: flash[:success].should == I18n.t('helpers.password_reset_successful')
       expected: "Password successfully updated"
            got: nil (using ==)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct your params:

```
post :reset_password, :reset_code => @user.reset_code, :user => { :password => @attr[:password], :password_confirmation => @attr[:password_confirmation] }
```

Comment: Ok, save your user before the post or use the same should receive as your previous question

Comment: User.should_receive(:find_by_reset_code).with(@user.reset_code).and_return @user  -- it's work. Thank you.

Comment: I only use the official site: https://www.relishapp.com/rspecand the book from rsoec's author D. Chelimsky